# Explanation of ssh command with option -D

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I am studying ssh and I haven't understood the following command with option `D`

```
ssh -D 9999 username@remotehost.net
```

can someone explain what this command does exactly with an example and when it is useful?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is intended as a programming Q&A. For questions like this about how to use basic Internet services, you might want to head over to http://SuperUser.com. I've voted to close this question, as it's off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will forward all packets to remotehost.net from localhost:9999 (in your example). In a nutshell this is socks proxy.

From ssh man page:

> Specifies a local “dynamic” application-level port forwarding.  This works by allocating a socket to listen to port on
>   the local
>            side, optionally bound to the specified bind_address.  Whenever a connection is made to this port, the connection is
>   forwarded over
>            the secure channel, and the application protocol is then used to determine where to connect to from the remote machine.  Currently
>            the SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 protocols are supported, and ssh will act as a SOCKS server.  Only root can forward privileged ports.
>            Dynamic port forwardings can also be specified in the configuration file.